# Django: null value in column "is_admin" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

**Simple Question: Why do I get this error:**

```
Integrity Error: null value in column "is_admin" violates not-null constraint
```

**When I Create a User with This Code?**

```
# views.py

user_obj = UserProfile.objects.create_user(
    username    = 'username',
    email       = 'test@example.com',
    password    = 'password',
)
```

---

---

---

---

The Error Sounds clear enough, except that I don't have a column called "is_admin" in my custom user model. I've tried specifying that "is_admin = False" in the code above and in the Customer user manager below, but when I do that, I get a new error that says `'is_admin' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` - Here are the details...

```
# models.py

### My Custom User Model Extending AbstractBaseUser
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email      = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username   = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    # ... other stuff [definitely nothing called "is_admin"]
    is_active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_editor  = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

As a sanity check, here is my Customer user manager:

```
# models.py

class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
        email       = self.normalize_email(email)
        username    = self.model.normalize_username(username)
        user        = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)

        # user      = self.model(username=username, email=email, is_admin = False, **extra_fields) ### I tried this, but I get the alternate error described in the paragraph above
        user.is_admin = False ### I added this in as a remedy. but I get the same error in the Title of this post

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And just to be sure, here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\MyApp\api\views.py", line 235, in cast_creator user_obj = create_user_with_just_an_email(email)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\MyApp\authenticate\views.py", line 316, in create_user_with_just_an_email password    = password,
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\MyApp\api\models.py", line 28, in create_user return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\MyApp\api\models.py", line 22, in _create_user user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 73, in save super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 718, in save force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 748, in save_base updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in _save_table result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 869, in _do_insertusing=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_metho return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _inser return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sq cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__ raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\myuser\MyApp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "is_admin" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: Wow, I've never see `is_admin` in Django before. Could you setup your logging to show the sql queries too?

Comment: Sounds like your database is out of sync with your models somehow. Did you have an `is_admin` field at one point? You could try running makemigrations again; otherwise if you don't mind losing data the easiest thing might be to drop your databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in django there are some permission related fields in User model. e.g. is_staff, is_admin, is_active, is_superuser. Since you are using your own custom model, you need to have these fields in model definition.

Comment: Ok, The answer belongs jointly to you and @Timur-Timerkhanov
You mentioned "Permissions" which reminded me of an old Git branch i had using Django's Custom permissions. I totally forgot I made an "is_admin" permission & related database migration. Despite switching to a new branch, those DB changes remained behind (obviously). That was the issue. The Fix was merging the old branch with the current branch (which was fine in my case). Manually altering the DB, as Timur-Timerkhanov suggested, would work in cases that you didn't want to merge in your old branch.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no is_admin field in default Django user models ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py)).

Seems like you have this field in the database with non-null constraint.

To remove is_admin field try to run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations api
python manage.py migrate api
```

If it didn't help try to drop this column from database. In case you're using postgres it would be something like

```
ALTER TABLE UserProfile 
DROP COLUMN is_admin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have applied a migration, and then rolled changes back (in some version control system).

**Important:** at this point, changes have been rolled back in your code, but not in the database table.

What you need to do is to checkout a branch, in which a migration was applied:

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

Undo this migration:

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> <N-1>
```

N here is the number at the start of your latest migrations file: `<migration>-003`